# Jquery for hover out of a div

Tags: jquery

I know this will make a `hoverOver` and `hoverOut` function on a given id:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").hover(
        function(){
            $("#div").css({"display":"block"});
        },
        function(){
            $("#div").css({"display":"none"});
        }
    )
});
```

But I want the `#div` to display as none when the mouse is out of the main div which holds every content with id of `#main` and to also fade out. So I ran this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").hover(
        function(){
            $("#div").css({"display":"block"});
        };
    $("#main").hoverOut(
        function(){
            $("#div").fadeOut('slow').css({"display":"none"});
        };
});
```

But the code isn't displaying the `#div` as none. Please am still new to jQuery, so I need help from anyone with a better idea. Here is the html for better explanation:

```
<div id="main">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="link">hover here</a>
    <div id="div">this is the content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`mouseenter()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)** and **[`mouseleave()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)**

As per documentation :

> **[`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)** method binds handlers for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.
>
> Calling `$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )` is shorthand for:
>   `$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#div").show(); // you can use show() method to show an element
  })
  $('#main').mouseleave(function() {
    $("#div").fadeOut('slow'); // fadeOut will hide the element, no need to hard-code css method 
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <a href="javascript:;" id="link">hover here</a>
  <div id="div">this is the content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked, but I more thing. I want the `mouseleave` to be with a `fadeOut('slow')` but its not working, please how do I run this?

Answer (score 0):

When your cursor enters main div it show #div and when cursor leave main div it hide #div i.e. display from block to back to none.

Jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#main").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#div").css('display','block');
});
$("#main").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#div").css('display','none');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

1. Use JS to set initial state as `display: none` as an inline style
2. When the mouse enters #link, fade in #div
3. When the mouse leaves #main, fade out #div

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#div").css("display", "none");
  $("#link").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $("#div").fadeIn('slow');
  });
  $("#main").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $("#div").fadeOut('slow');
  });

});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxrRJZ